# Start Quartz Scheduler without firing the triggers

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, spring-scheduled, quartz

I have got q requirement where I need to start the scheduler but the existing triggers should not run. I have spring boot application, I want to implement a case where I will start the application but it should not run the existing triggers into the system.

It can be any flag or parameter base. Is there any way to achieve this? I have been checking on web related to this but could not find anything related to this.

Comment: Can you please describe your problem in detail like Which technology you are using ? When Scheduler should run ? Are you using spring-boot? then you can use @EnableScheduling at main class.

Comment: @ChiragShah updated the description. Yes, I have a spring boot application. For some cases, I want to start my application but it should not run existing triggers into the system.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly what you can do, create the scheduler instance, but do not set autostart to true. Then application will be started, but no triggers will be executed.

The code fragment is on kotlin, but it should be similar on java

```
@Bean
open fun quartzScheduler(springBeanJobFactory: SpringBeanJobFactory): SchedulerFactoryBean {
    val quartzSchedulerFactory = SchedulerFactoryBean()
    quartzSchedulerFactory.setJobFactory(springBeanJobFactory)
    quartzSchedulerFactory.setConfigLocation(ClassPathResource("quartz.properties"))
    quartzSchedulerFactory.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true)
    quartzSchedulerFactory.isAutoStartup = false

    return quartzSchedulerFactory
}
```

Then you can create some simple controller to start the scheduler

```
schedulerFactory.scheduler.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Variation written in Java and using application properties

```java
    @Bean
    @Inject
    SchedulerFactoryBeanCustomizer schedulerCustomizer(
            @Value("${spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName:schedulerFactoryBean}") String schedulerName,
            @Value("${spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.enabled:true}") boolean enabled) {
        return (schedulerFactoryBean) -> {
            schedulerFactoryBean.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
            schedulerFactoryBean.setBeanName(schedulerName);
            schedulerFactoryBean.setAutoStartup(enabled);
        };
    }
```